# Is it possible to disable the bounding box in yolov8 after crop?

Tags: crop, yolo, bounding-box, yolov8

I want to make a crop of an object found by YOLOV8. I already have a trained model which detects the object and cuts it out but the bounding box always remains in the cutout. I don't know if it is possible to remove the bounding box

I'm trying this code but it doesn't work

!yolo task=detect mode=predict model='/content/last.pt' conf=0.45 source='/content/images' boxes=False hide_conf=True hide_labels=True save_crop=True